# Ignore Battery Optimisation not working on Oneplus 5

Tags: android, optimization, battery

Currently using `powerManager.isIgnoringBatteryOptimizations(getPackageName())` for devices running api >= 23.

And requesting user to allow my app to be not optimised by using

`Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));`

This works on most of the devices, but on Oneplus devices even after user allowing it to be not optimised, I see no effect, my application is still optimised and I miss `SMS_RECEIVED` broadcast.

Oneplus device with Oxygen OS 5.0.1 and Android OS 8.0.0

Comment: This is the song of my people!

I can confirm that the OnePlus 3T does the same - both before and after the upgrade to Android 9, and despite the user explicitly confirming that the app may run without battery optimisations.

Comment: you may use this     context.startActivity(new Intent(
                            Settings.ACTION_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATION_SETTINGS)); you have to allow your not to be OPTIMIZED from the setting Activity.